# Mathematical notation of substring

Tags: notation

Let $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ be an ordered set.

Is there any established mathematical notation for the first $k$ (resp. last $k$ ) elements of this ordered set?

This corresponds to the computer science equivalent of "substring".

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't even an established mathematical notation for "ordered set".  "List" is common, but that's more cs than math.  "Ordered $n$-tuple" is standard, but it limits you to exactly $n$ objects.

Comment: There's an established notation that $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ denotes a set, not an ordered set.

Comment: It looks like you're talking about finite sets, so in your case an ordered set $X$ is essentially a set $X$ with an order function (bijective) $f:X→\{x\in N^+ | x<|X|\}$, i.e. just a sequence.

Comment: @AI.G. with that definition there would be nothing stopping any element from X be put in the same position $x \in N^+$, would there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say the following. Let $a_1 < a_2 < \ldots < a_n$ be a chain.
For $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$, the chain $a_1 < a_2 < \ldots < a_k$ is called the *prefix* of length $k$ of the original chain. Its *suffix* of length $k$ is the chain $a_{n-k + 1} < \ldots < a_n$.